# What am I missing in this Python math problem set

Tags: python, math, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator that tells you how many months it will take to save for the down payment on some house given salary, percentage saved, etc. I've gotten the code to work through the end, my math is just off at some point, and I don't know where. Any help would be great.

Instructions: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf

```
annual_salary = float(input('What is your annual salary?\n'))

portion_saved = float(input('What percent of your income will you save annually (decimal form)?\n'))

total_cost = float(input('What is the total cost of the home?\n'))


portion_down_payment = .25 * total_cost

current_savings = 0

months = 0


monthly_saved = (annual_salary / 12) * portion_saved

monthly_total = (monthly_saved * .04) + monthly_saved

while current_savings < portion_down_payment:

    current_savings = current_savings + monthly_total

    months = months + 1

else:

    print(months)
```

Comment: instaed of this "monthly_saved = (annual_salary / 12) * portion_saved" what do you get with this "monthly_saved = (annual_salary / 12.0) * portion_saved"  ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "my math is just off at some point"? Just what input gave you wrong output? Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user1438644: That's only an issue in Python 2. This user looks to be using Python 3 (where `print` is a function and `input` returns strings that need to be converted to numbers, rather than numbers directly). Though since `annual_salary` is explicitly converted to a float, it should probably work in Python 2 anyway (`x / y` only truncates in Python 2 if both values are integers).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is how you're computing the interest on the person's savings. It looks like you're giving them an extra 4% of every savings contribution, but that ignores the compounding nature of savings. You probably want to move that 4% computation into the loop, so that the interest earned is based on all of the savings balance:

```
current_savings = 0
months = 0
monthly_saved = (annual_salary / 12) * portion_saved

while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    current_savings = current_savings * 1.04 + monthly_saved     # 4% monthly interest
    months = months + 1

print(months)
```

Now, this code assumes that the 4% you were using is the appropriate interest rate for a monthly calculation. If that's an annual interest rate (i.e. an APR), you probably need to divide it by 12 to get the correct monthly rate.

Answer (score 0):

after messing around with it for a minute I realized you need to calculate your interest before adding the following months salary or you get close but not quite...This code outputs the same as MITs test cases.

```
#Write a program to calculate how many months it will take you to save up enough 
#money for a down
#payment. You will want your main variables to be floats, so you should cast user 
#inputs to floats.

annual_salary = 0
total_cost = 0
portion_saved = 0


try:
    annual_salary =  float(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
    portion_saved = float(input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: "))
    total_cost = float(input("Enter the cost of your dream home: "))
except:
    print("Please make sure you input a number")

returns = 0.04
portion_down_payment = 0.25
down_payment = total_cost * portion_down_payment

monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12
monthly_save = monthly_salary * portion_saved
current_savings = 0

months = 1

while current_savings < down_payment:

    investments = (current_savings * returns) / 12 #investment return first otherwise you get close but not close enough
    current_savings += investments
    current_savings += monthly_save
    months += 1
```